# Read in of .dat file into R

Tags: r

Sample data

```
    DATA FILE LINE 1 CONTAINS 6 VARIABLES
3-29 Arlanta hoozers      4  7 status
```

R Code

```
    > myfile <- read.fwf(
        +    file        = "events.dat",
        +    width       = c(4,10,8,2,2,8),
        +    col.names   = c("date", "city", 
             "nickname", 
             "won", "lost", "status"),
        +    colClasses  = c("character", "character", 
            "character", "numeric", "numeric", 
            "character"),
        +    na.strings=".",
        +    sep=" ",
        +    strip.white = TRUE,
        + )
```

Error in read.table(file = FILE, header = header, sep = sep, row.names = row.names,  : 
  more columns than column names

What is this error message telling me? 
The date looks suspicious. I can't use lubridate package until I can read in the data.

Suggestions here? I am having difficulty deciding on which read command to use for my input files. Should I let the extension be my quide?  Thanks. MM

Comment: Hi @mary,, do all the lines have the same amount of variables? If so, please try read.delim(events.dat)

Comment: There were missing data for some observations but your approach worked. I am going to collect information about each read in function and see if I can figure out a flow chart of how to approach these. The delim function includes an option sep="\t". What does that mean? Thank you. MM

Comment: I am going to answer your question with my previous response and provide a response to your next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments this solution worked for you:

`read.delim(events.dat)`

To answer your f/u question the `sep="\t"` means that the separator is a tab.   R likes that command better than inseting an actual tab into quotes.